# Como subir archivos desde webview con php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript, android, android-studio

procederé a explicar todo lo mas detalladamente posible.

Mi sistema es PHP y hice uso del framework Materialize. 
Hay 2 formularios que requieren subir archivos.

Form 1- Requiere subir una foto (JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF).

Form 2- Requiere subir un archivo o foto (PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, DOC, XLS, DOCX, PPT, XLSX).

Este es mi código:

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12"> <!-- Tamano del input-field Upload-File-->
<div class="file-field input-field">
 <div class="btn blue">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
 <span>Archivo</span>
 <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
 </div>
 <div class="file-path-wrapper">
 <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, DOC, XLS, DOCX, PPT, XLSX">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

En cuanto a android, tengo un webview:

```
WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://mi.pagina.com");
    }
```

**PROBLEMA: Cuando presiono para subir el archivo no sucede nada.**

Estuve leyendo mucho, y parece que hay que agregar mucho código, pero creo que varia en la versión de android.

Por el momento agregue esto el Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Y probé con varios códigos que aparecen en este foro, pero ninguno me funciona.

Foros: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907369/file-upload-in-webview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666844/onshowfilechooser-from-android-webview-works-only-once

Agradecería su ayuda.

**EDITADO:**

Probé con este código:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/tree/master/input-file-example/app/src/main

- La app inicia y funciona todo perfecto, así que asumo que ese código funciona perfecto, pero no inicia el FILE, así que pienso que falta algo de código pero javascript en el servidor

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no se realiza ninguna acción en este caso, **únicamente si la acción proviene de un redirect**, como prueba, puedes usar esta aplicación que contiene un log y puedes ver las acciones que se realizan cuando interactuas con el contenido cargado dentro del `WebView`
:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-WebView-Logging

Lo que se necesita es crear una [interfaz](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html), realizando la declaración en la página:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

y el llamado en el `WebView`, para que el `WebView` detecte la acción realizada mediante `JavaScript` :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");
```

En la documentación puedes ver la información acerca de la [interfaz Javascript](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: Te entiendo, pero que pondría en el caso mio, es decir, para que se abra el selector de archivos en el cel?