# Webview no carga audios concretos dentro de la web

Tags: android, android-fragment, webview-android

Buenas,

Tengo un problema con mi WebView, yo uso mi dispositivo móvil abro cualquier navegador (Chrome, Firefox), entro dentro de la web que quiero cargar en mi webview y navego sin problemas. Incluso puedo reproducir audios que están dentro de la web. Por ejemplo esta web: http://www2.radioecca.org/radio/carta/a-nuestro-aire/12038598

Pero dentro de mi aplicación, yo tengo un Fragment con un webview que me carga la página web perfectamente, pero a la hora de reproducir el audio, no hace nada.

Este es el código de mi Fragment:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")//Activa contenido javascript en el webview
public class FragmentIvooxWebView extends Fragment {

private WebView webView;
private int iContNored = 0;/*Contador de veces mostrados los mensajes de no hay red*/

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        isNetworkConnected(getContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Método que muestra el layout con el webview
 * @param inflater
 * @param container
 * @param savedInstanceState
 * @return
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ivoox_webview, container, false);
    webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webViewIvoox);
    return view;
}

/**
 * Método que valida si el dispositivo tiene conexión a internet.
 * De ser afirmativo, llama al método webview para cargar la web
 * @param ctx
 * @return Devuelve un boolean.
 * @throws Exception
 */
public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context ctx) throws Exception {
    NetworkInfo ni = null;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new Exception("Se ha producido un error al intentar validar la conección a Internet");
    }
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active networks.
        if(iContNored < 2){
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Aviso\n" +
                    "No está conectado a ninguna red, revise su conexión Wifi o Datos móviles" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            iContNored++;
        }
        return false;
    } else{
        try {
            webView();
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Método que carga la web de ivoox
 */
private void webView(){
    //Cargando el Webview con par�metros espec�ficos
    WebSettings webSettings =  this . webView . getSettings ();
    webSettings . setJavaScriptEnabled ( true );
    webSettings . setDomStorageEnabled ( true );
    this . webView . setWebViewClient ( new WebViewClient());
    this . webView . setWebChromeClient ( new WebChromeClient());
    webSettings . setLoadWithOverviewMode ( true );
    webSettings . setUseWideViewPort ( true );

    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;
                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    //Carga la url en el webview
    webView.loadUrl("http://www2.radioecca.org/radio/carta/a-nuestro-aire/12038598");

    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Este es el error que da:

```
04-07 10:14:49.278 2710-3213/ecca.radio E/EGL_emulation: eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
04-07 10:14:49.278 2710-3213/ecca.radio E/EGL_emulation: tid 3213: eglQueryContext(1484): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
04-07 10:14:49.615 2710-2710/ecca.radio I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ivoox.com/player_ej_12038598_4_1.html?c1=0069ad' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://files.ivoox.com/listen/12038598'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.", source: https://www.ivoox.com/player_ej_12038598_4_1.html?c1=0069ad (0)
```

Curiosamente yo antes cargaba otra página en el webview y si me dejaba escuchar los audios: http://m.ivoox.com/escuchar-radio-ecca_nq_646_1.html

### EDICIÓN 1:

El problema lo estoy teniendo dentro de un iframe.
Si yo uso el iframe a continuación, no funciona.

```
<iframe id="audio_12038598" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE; box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;" src="https://www.ivoox.com/player_ej_12038598_4_1.html?c1=0069ad"></iframe>
```

Pero si uso el siguiente iframe, si funciona.

```
<iframe id="audio_12038598" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" height="200" style="border:1px solid #EEE; box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;" src="http://www.ivoox.com/player_ej_12038598_4_1.html?c1=0069ad"></iframe>
```

Lo único que cambia de un iframe a otro es el https por http.

Este iframe es autogenerado por la plataforma ivoox, y no tengo manera de tocarlo. 
¿Hay alguna manera de que el `webview acepte iframes con https`?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda. Estoy aprendiendo mucho de esta comunidad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solucionado.

He cambiado la forma en la que se generan los iframes, ahora obliga a poner siempre la url con http desde la página web.

Un saludo y muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si pruebas esto en el navegador del dispositivo puede funcionar sin duda pero si cargas la página en un `WebView` puede no funcionar correctamente:

Este es una pregunta en la cual quiere realizar en un WebView lo mismo que realiza en un navegador:
**"La principal razón es que en Android a diferencia por ejemplo de iOS el `WebView` tiene un navegador limitado."**

[¿ Cómo localizar en un mapa múltiples destinos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30559/c%C3%B3mo-localizar-en-un-mapa-m%C3%BAltiples-destinos/30582#30582)

y esta es otra similar:

[Como subir archivos desde webview con php y javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60976/como-subir-archivos-desde-webview-con-php-y-javascript)

**La opción en este caso es usar una [interfaz](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html), y el método que se mande llamar en la aplicación reproduzca el audio.**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, he estado haciendo pruebas y he editado la pregunta con más información sobre el problema.